# PHP - Sorting an array against another key

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array ($array) with various values such as

```
{"name":"Name1","date":"Mar 27 2017, 01:02:19","comment":"Comment 1","commentid":"48286925"}
{"name":"Name2","date":"Mar 27 2017, 03:55:01","comment":"Comment 2","commentid":"66838672","replytocomment":"33827596"}
{"name":"Name3","date":"Mar 27 2017, 04:49:23","comment":"Comment 3","commentid":"33827596"}
```

I already managed to put them in order via descending date. So $array[0]['comment'] would be "Comment 1"

As you can see, $array[2] has an extra key "replytocomment" with the same value as the "commentid" of $array[3]

What I want to do is sort array values like that under their matches (since the array value with a matching "replytocomment" to another array's "commentid" is the reply to it, it needs to go underneath it.)

So the sorted order of $array would be

```
{"name":"Name1","date":"Mar 27 2017, 01:02:19","comment":"Comment 1","commentid":"48286925"}
{"name":"Name3","date":"Mar 27 2017, 04:49:23","comment":"Comment 3","commentid":"33827596"}
{"name":"Name2","date":"Mar 27 2017, 03:55:01","comment":"Comment 2","commentid":"66838672","replytocomment":"33827596"}
```

Ignore the fact that the "response" has a newer timestamp than what it was responding to, it's just some simplified example lines I made up

Comment: Could you illustrate what you want in the form of a table?

Comment: If you’re trying to treat this array of arrays as a table, consider (a) setting `replytocomment` in the other arrays to `null` or something, so that you have something to sort on, or (b) storing the data in an SQLite database, so you can let the database to the sort.

Comment: It would be more appropriate to handle it with database.